# updating open layers popup with asynch URL request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, openlayers

My mapsApp uses openLayers popup for markers on the map.  When I create the pop-up I prepopulate it with a link and a CSS spinner.  I then launch an asynch URL request.

What I want to do is then remove the spinner and add the info I receive back from the URL request afterward.  I can't figure out how to reference the html portion of the popup (finalString).

Here's the code I have.

```
function showPopUp (markerID,itemID) {

// **Tested** this creates a spinner and works with CSS

wxString =   "<div class=\"spinner\" style=\"width: 34px; height: 34px\"><div class=\"bar1\"></div><div class=\"bar2\"></div><div class=\"bar3\"></div><div class=\"bar4\"></div><div class=\"bar5\"></div><div class=\"bar6\"></div><div class=\"bar7\"></div><div class=\"bar8\"></div><div class=\"bar9\"></div><div class=\"bar10\"></div><div class=\"bar11\"></div><div class=\"bar12\"></div></div>";
}

var markerString =   "<a title=\""+itemID+"\" href=\"http://www.mywebsite.com/item/"+itemID+"\" target=\"_blank\">"+itemID+"</a>";
var finalString = markerString + "</br>"+ wxString;

popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(icaoID,
                     markerID.lonlat,
                     new OpenLayers.Size(200, 200),
                     finalString,
                     null, true);

map.addPopup(popup);
getWX(itemID,popup);        //asynch request that will remove the popup
}
```

my getWx function uses an XMLhttp request

```
function getWX (item) {

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {                          // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {     //If finished loading

        return xmlhttp.responseText; 
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","getwx.php?q=" + item,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: I have found a better answer, see my edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you with the first step - the access to your popup object. But I haven't found out how to change the text once you called the constructor.

(**EDIT**
The Popup object has a `setContentHTML` function, which would be inherited by `FramedCloud` class.)

You are calling the `getWX` function with two parameters, but you only accept one. Start by adding the popup object to that like this:

```
function getWX (item, popup)
```

then when the call is ready (readyState == 4), change the popups text:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {     //If finished loading

    popup.setContentHTML(xmlhttp.responseText); 
}
```

Maybe it's easier if you waited for the text before you create the popup?

Then it would be something like this:

Pass in a reference to the map object:

```
function getWX (item, map)
```

Create the popup when the text is ready:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {     //If finished loading
     popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(icaoID,
                 markerID.lonlat,
                 new OpenLayers.Size(200, 200),
                 finalString,
                 null, true);

    map.addPopup(popup);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed the missing parameter was going to use that to reference the popup.  I do not want to delay the creation of the pop up as I want the user to be able to use the link and if they want to wait for the getWX function they can

Comment: This is a good answer if i want the user to wait.  if i get no other answer for what i want i will mark it as an answer and vote it up.

Comment: @MB. I found how to set the text: the method `setContentHTML` on the Popup object, which FramedCloud inherits. Will edit my answer.

Comment: Great to be able to help out :-)